# Set and Change Button Image by Cliciking on it WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, onclick

I've got a class, which holds 8 BitmapImage in an array. 
The Images are added in the following way in the class constructor:

```
  public SymbolCollection(string[] symbolNames)
        {
            Symbols = new BitmapImage[8];

            for (int i = 0; i < Symbols.Length; i++)
            {
                Symbols[i] = new BitmapImage();
                Symbols[i].BeginInit();
                Symbols[i].UriSource = new Uri(@"/Resources/" + symbolNames[i] + ".png", UriKind.Relative);
                Symbols[i].EndInit();
            }

        }
```

The button's ImageSource are set to the following:

```
 <Button x:Name="buttonPlayer1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="44,387,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Click="OnPlayerSymbolClick">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Content}"/>
             </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

I tried to set the image to the button in the MainWindow() method and change it in the OnPlayerSymbolClick() method, but the image doesn't even show up:

```
public MainWindow()
{   
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SetSymbolCollection();

    Uri u = symbolCollectionHolder[0].Symbols[0].UriSource;
    Debug.WriteLine(u.ToString());
    Image i = new Image();
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.UriSource = u;
    i.Source = bmp;
    buttonPlayer1.Content = i;
}


private void OnPlayerSymbolClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ImageBrush imagebrush = new ImageBrush();
    imagebrush.ImageSource = symbolCollectionHolder[0].Symbols[1];
    buttonPlayer1.Background = imagebrush;
    buttonPlayer1.Content = imagebrush;
    Debug.WriteLine(buttonPlayer1.Background.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(imagebrush.ImageSource.ToString());
}
```

The Build Action for the png-s are set to Resource and there's a Resources folder in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an image resource file is to be loaded into a BitmapImage in code behind, you should use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Symbols[i] = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/Resources/" + symbolNames[i] + ".png"));
```

---

Besides that, setting the Content or Background property is pointless when the Button's Template doesn't use these properties.

You probably wanted to write the Template like this:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonPlayer1" ...>
    <Button.Template>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
             <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

which would require an `ImageSource` (or a derived object) as value of the Button's Content.

You could directly pass one of your Symbols:

```
buttonPlayer1.Content = Symbols[0];
```

Comment: With the TemplateBinding Content modification, everything works. Thank you very much!